# Fitting an AR1 process to a sparse time series

Tags: regression, arima, autocorrelation, intermittent-time-series

Say I have a sparse time series, i.e., containing many zeros. Furthermore, the values in the time series can only be positive or zero.

I want to test for the autocorrelation, i.e., fit an AR1 process to the data. Can I do so in a meaningful way without doing any transformation to the data? Or does it not make sense to fit such a process to this kind of sparse data?

Comment: In the context of time series analysis, containing many zeros is probably not the usual definition of sparse. Just so you know.

Comment: What is the nature of the zeros ? Are they structural, because the actual underlying measured value is zero, or do they represent the absence of a measurement ? You may be able to apply other techniques.